# Angular - many imports/exports modules, is that safe?

Tags: angular

I'm just wondering if this is a safe and good practise to do things like this:

```
@NgModule({
  import: [ ComponentANeedThisModule ],
  declarations: [ ComponentA ],
  exports: [ ComponentA ]
})
export class ModuleA

@NgModule({
  import: [ ComponentBNeedThisModule ],
  declarations: [ ComponentB ],
  exports: [ ComponentB ]
})
export class ModuleB

@NgModule({
  import: [ ModuleA, ModuleB ],
})
export class MainModule

// MainModule html
<app-component-a></app-component-a>
<app-component-b></app-component-b>
```

My app is sliced into many small reusable modules. And I don't want to have one big SharedModule. I prefer import only this module which I need, not whole SharedModule.

Does it good?

Comment: What do you mean by safe? Can you elaborate on why a shared module is a bad idea in this case?

Comment: I mean, does this idea cause some loading/performance problems? I have ~50 components in my app, and in MyModuleA I only need 3 of them, for example. So I don't want to import all SharedModule (which exports all 50 components), I prefer import onlny this 3. In MyModuleB I need 10 of them, so again. I prefer import onlny this 10, not 50. I hope I described it well

Comment: @matiKamp it does have an impact on loading for lazy modules, but it's difficult to control it because WebPack does some unexpected things to bundles. If you have a large shared module and only 1 component is used by the main application. The entire module must be loaded to boot the app. Angular not not load a partial module. It's all or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just wondering if this is a safe and good practise to do things like this:

This is actually the recommended approach. Breaking down your modules into smaller pieces yields the best results from tree shaking.

Some libraries like Angular Material for example, place each component into individual modules and then allow consumers to import just the modules they need for their application.

Angular will only bundle the modules that have been used. So while many modules are declared only the ones consumed are added to the bundle.

There is no point in separating things into multiple modules if the application will always consume everything. So a recommended approach is to create feature modules that encompass everything relative to a single feature.

https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules

> So if I have one big SharedModule (which exports ~50 components) and I import this module to MyModule, but in MyModule I use only one component - it means that during the build only this one component will be bundled?

Any components declared in the *exports* part of a module can not be dropped from the module. From a tree shaking perspective the *exports* is a contract of what features a module provides. Angular can not search outside the scope of a module to see what is consuming those *exports*. So if your SharedModule is exporting 50 components then they all must be bundled that way.

Any components declared in the bootstrap section of a module can not be dropped, because those components have been reserved for dynamic factory creation.

Everything defined in the *providers* section of a module must stay in the bundle. A module becomes the parent provider to child modules, but a module can *override* providers previously declared. So Angular can not *inspect* the *usage* of a provider and make assumptions that it can be dropped.

Components defined in the *declarations* that are excluded from *exports* and *bootstrap* are eligible for tree shaking. With that said, I have struggled to find a credible reference to the Angular documentation that states this is the case. The only way to know for sure is to build production and use a bundle inspector.

https://coryrylan.com/blog/analyzing-bundle-size-with-the-angular-cli-and-webpack

In Angular 6 and above they added a `provideIn` parameter for the `@Injectable()` decorator for services. This added tree shaking support to services, because they can now search to see if any components inject the service. If no components consume the service it can be dropped from the bundles.

I do not know the full details of how it works, but I found this reference:

https://coryrylan.com/blog/tree-shakeable-providers-and-services-in-angular

Comment: So if I have one big SharedModule (which exports ~50 components) and I import this module to MyModule, but in MyModule I use only one component - it means that during the build only this one component will be bundled?

Comment: @matiKamp I have to be careful answering that question, because they changed Angular's tree shaking in version 6 and up. Let me see if I can find up to date info on how it currently works.

Answer (score 1):

It's one way of doing modules. Since Angular is fairly opinionated in style, the most consistent reference seems to be [the Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules). I linked you to their *LIFT* reference, but reading a few more pages down has some "good" recommendations for the application (and module) structure.

This is basically what the [Angular Material library](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib) does. I'm actually with you, I prefer to avoid large share modules. One of the reasons is for faster builds/testing. If the build process doesn't have to eliminate an excessive amount of unused shared resources, building and testing will remain faster.

---

Part way through writing this, [cgTag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277286/10747134) said the rest.